# slick 2.0.0-M2: How to define custom types (MappedTypeMapper in slick 1.0.0)?

Tags: scala, slick, custom-type, playframework-2.2

I want to define a custom type in slick 2.0.0-M2. The type has an underlying scala type that is known to slick (for example String). In Slick 1.0.0 I could do something like:

```
class Test[UnderlyingType : TypeMapper] {
  case class MyType(elem: UnderlyingType)

  implicit val typeMapper = MappedTypeMapper.base[MyType, UnderlyingType](_.elem, t=>MyType(t))
}
```

(code above not tested, but my implementation was similar to that)

How does this work in slick 2.0.0-M2? The MappedTypeMapper class vanished...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called `MappedColumnType` now. Also see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scalaquery/4Ns_J_8wbqQ/0SGiJL4O8A8J